# Does there exist a set which is its own complement? If so can you give an example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible that there exist a set $U$ that has the property $U=U^c$?

Comment: I guess if the universal set is the empty set.

Comment: By the principle of extensionality, two sets are equal when they contain the same elements.  Can the complement of a set $U$ contain the *same* elements as $U$ does?

Comment: @Nameless:  Wouldn't the universal set have to contain the empty set?  So in most understandings the universal set is not empty.

Comment: @hardmath, I guess that's true, but every set contains itself anyways.

Comment: @Nameless:  I'm distinguishing the relationship of a set containing its elements from that of a set containing *subsets*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the universal set in question.

For a particular universe, $\Omega$, we define the complement of a subset $A$ of $\Omega$ as:

$A^c = \Omega\setminus A=\{x~:~x\in \Omega~\text{and}~x\notin A\}$

In the case that $\Omega$ is nonempty, then there is some $x\in \Omega$.  This implies that exactly one of the following is true: $x\in A$ or $x\in A^c$.  Since it cannot be that $x$ is in *both*, we see that $A\neq A^c$.

*If you allow for your universal set to be empty*, I.e. in the case that $\Omega=\emptyset$, then the *only* subset of $\Omega$ is the empty set.

You have in that case $\emptyset^c = \emptyset\setminus \emptyset = \emptyset$

Because this is a particularly uninteresting scenario and provides difficulties for definitions in measure theory and probability, we usually do *not* allow our universal sets to be empty.

Comment: Yeah, but it may be the interesting scenario

Comment: It depends I guess how you define empty

Comment: There is only one definition of an empty set, and that is the set with no elements.  I.e. $\emptyset = \{~\}$ and satisfies the property $\forall x\in \Omega, x\notin \emptyset$.

Comment: Every element *in the universe* is in the universe.  However, there can be elements not in the universe.  You cannot have a set of all sets.  That leads to Russel's Paradox.

Comment: Every element is in universe, a single element cannot be an element of empty set. The first property is ok. But, the second one is a bit strange. Plus, it is recursive. Meaning that you use ∅ in the definition. You use the thing to define the thing

Comment: The definition that $\emptyset = \{~\}$ is not recursive in any way.  The additional property was a side note and is not a part of the definition.

Comment: So what does ∅={ } mean? There are no elements in the empty set? Still there is empty there

Comment: ∅={ } simply is a change of variable by itself and has no impications

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set or go to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ if you still have concerns.

Comment: ok. thanks for your replies.